# How to create a selection rectangle with rotate, resize and move abilities?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, math, geometry

I'm trying to make a selection rectangle, with the possibility to change its position and its size and also to rotate it - everything will be done by dragging the mouse.

I was successful with moving, but I have a problem with rotating and resizing.

Resizing works fine before the rotation, but after the rotation the rectangle changes position while resizing.

On rotation the first time, everything seems to work fine, but the second time the rectangle jumps and changes position.

Attached is a picture, and the code I wrote.

How can I make `RotateThumb` and `CenterBottomThumb` work properly?

I uploaded a full project to GitHub, [here](https://github.com/codedom-git/SelectionRect).

[image]

```xml
<Window x:Class="SelectionRect.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SelectionRect"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="400"
        Height="400"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:RectModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="7" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="7" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas1">
            <Grid Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" Name="RectGrid"
                  Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}"
                  Width="{Binding Width}"
                  Height="{Binding Height}">
                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}" />
                </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <Border Background="#4C0000FF" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" />

                <Thumb Name="LeftTopThumb"
                       Margin="-5,-5,0,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Cursor="SizeNWSE"
                       DragDelta="LeftTopThumb_DragDelta"
                       Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle}" />
                <Thumb Name="RightTopThumb"
                       Margin="0,-5,-5,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Cursor="SizeNESW"
                       DragDelta="RightTopThumb_DragDelta"
                       Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle}" />
                <Thumb Name="LeftBottomThumb"
                       Margin="-5,0,0,-5"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Cursor="SizeNESW"
                       DragDelta="LeftBottomThumb_DragDelta"
                       Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle}" />
                <Thumb Name="RightBottomThumb"
                       Margin="0,0,-5,-5"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Cursor="SizeNWSE"
                       DragDelta="RightBottomThumb_DragDelta"
                       Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle}" />

                <Thumb Name="CenterBottomThumb"
                       Margin="0,0,0,-5"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Cursor="SizeNS"
                       DragDelta="CenterBottomThumb_DragDelta"
                       Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle}" />

                <Thumb Name="CenterTopThumb"
                       Margin="0,-5,0,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Cursor="SizeNS"
                       DragDelta="CenterTopThumb_DragDelta"
                       Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle}" />

                <Thumb Name="RotateThumb"
                       Margin="0,-25,0,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Cursor="Cross"
                       DragDelta="RotateThumb_DragDelta"
                       DragStarted="RotateThumb_DragStarted"
                       Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle}" />

                <Thumb Name="CenterLeftThumb"
                       Margin="-5,0,0,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Cursor="SizeWE"
                       DragDelta="CenterLeftThumb_DragDelta"
                       Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle}" />

                <Thumb Name="CenterRightThumb"
                       Margin="0,0,-5,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Cursor="SizeWE"
                       DragDelta="CenterRightThumb_DragDelta"
                       Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle}" />

                <Thumb x:Name="CenterThumb"
                       Width="Auto"
                       Height="Auto"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                       Cursor="SizeAll"
                       DragDelta="CenterThumb_DragDelta"
                       Focusable="True">
                    <Thumb.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border Name="CenterThumbBorder"
                                    Margin="10"
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    MouseDown="CenterThumbBorder_MouseDown" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Thumb.Template>
                </Thumb>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Linq;

namespace SelectionRect
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private double _initialLeft;
        private double _initialTop;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new RectModel() { Height = 200, Width = 100 , Left = 20, Top = 50};
        }

        private void CenterBottomThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            var thumb = sender as Thumb;
            var model = thumb.DataContext as RectModel;

            if (model.Height + e.VerticalChange >= 1)
            {
                model.Height += e.VerticalChange;
            }
        }

        private void CenterTopThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void RotateThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            var thumb = sender as Thumb;
            var model = thumb.DataContext as RectModel;

            var initialAngle = model.Angle;
            var center = new Point(model.CenterX, model.CenterY);
            center = RectGrid.TranslatePoint(center, Canvas1);
            var currentPos = Mouse.GetPosition(Canvas1);
            model.Angle = center.GetAngle(currentPos) + 90;

            var Rect = new Rect(_initialLeft, _initialTop, model.Width, model.Height);
            var cornerPoints = new[] { Rect.TopLeft, Rect.TopRight, Rect.BottomRight, Rect.BottomLeft };
            var m = new Matrix();

            m.RotateAt(model.Angle, center.X, center.Y);
            m.Transform(cornerPoints);

            model.Left = cornerPoints.Min(p => p.X);
            model.Top = cornerPoints.Min(p => p.Y);
        }

        private void RotateThumb_DragStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            var thumb = sender as Thumb;
            var model = thumb.DataContext as RectModel;

            _initialLeft = model.Left;
            _initialTop = model.Top;
        }

        private void CenterLeftThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CenterRightThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CenterThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            var thumb = sender as Thumb;
            var model = thumb.DataContext as RectModel;
            model.Top += e.VerticalChange;
            model.Left += e.HorizontalChange;
        }

        private void CenterThumbBorder_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void LeftBottomThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void LeftTopThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void RightTopThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void RightBottomThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    public static class Ex
    {
       public static double GetAngle(this System.Windows.Point p1, System.Windows.Point p2)
       {
           var xDiff = p2.X - p1.X;
           var yDiff = p2.Y - p1.Y;
           return Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180.0 / Math.PI;
       }
    }
    class RectModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _Angle;
        public double Angle
        {
            get { return _Angle; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _Angle) return;
                _Angle = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Angle));
            }
        }

        private double _Height;
        public double Height
        {
            get { return _Height; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _Height) return;
                _Height = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Height));
            }
        }

        private double _Width;
        public double Width
        {
            get { return _Width; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _Width) return;
                _Width = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Width));
            }
        }

        private double _Top;
        public double Top
        {
            get { return _Top; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _Top) return;
                _Top = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Top));
            }
        }

        private double _Left;
        public double Left
        {
            get { return _Left; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _Left) return;
                _Left = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Left));
            }
        }

        public double CenterX => Width / 2;
        public double CenterY => Height / 2;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've not moved your origin correctly. The point which your rotate transform rotates around.

Comment: What you're trying to do is already implemented in WPF, it's called the _Adorners_ library, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/adorners-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Dai Thank you, could you please post an answer with working code?

Comment: @codeDom I _could_, but I'm too lazy

Comment: @Dai I quite doubt you can... ;) Two others with a high reputation didn't make it, just for now I hope...

Answer (score 0):

The transformation origin and the coordinate space change when you apply rotation: you should make sure the transformation origin for the rotation is set to the center of the rectangle. That will make the rotation behavior more predictable.
And when resizing, you need to take into account the current rotation to correctly calculate the new size and position.

In `RotateThumb_DragDelta`, you are recalculating the angle correctly, but you also need to adjust the position of the rectangle after rotation to make sure it remains in place. That involves recalculating the `Left` and `Top` properties considering the new angle.
Modify the method to adjust the position based on the rotation. You might need to calculate the new bounds of the rectangle after rotation and set `Left` and `Top` accordingly.

```cs
private void RotateThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    var thumb = sender as Thumb;
    var model = thumb.DataContext as RectModel;

    var initialAngle = model.Angle;
    var center = new Point(model.CenterX, model.CenterY);
    center = RectGrid.TranslatePoint(center, Canvas1);
    var currentPos = Mouse.GetPosition(Canvas1);
    model.Angle = center.GetAngle(currentPos) + 90;

    var rotatedRect = RotateRect(new Rect(_initialLeft, _initialTop, model.Width, model.Height), model.Angle, center);
    model.Left = rotatedRect.Left;
    model.Top = rotatedRect.Top;
}

private Rect RotateRect(Rect rect, double angle, Point center)
{
    var cornerPoints = new[] { rect.TopLeft, rect.TopRight, rect.BottomRight, rect.BottomLeft };
    var m = new Matrix();
    m.RotateAt(angle, center.X, center.Y);
    m.Transform(cornerPoints);

    double minX = cornerPoints.Min(p => p.X);
    double minY = cornerPoints.Min(p => p.Y);
    double maxX = cornerPoints.Max(p => p.X);
    double maxY = cornerPoints.Max(p => p.Y);

    return new Rect(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
}
```

You would also need to implement the logic for the `DragDelta` events of the other thumbs (`CenterTopThumb`, `CenterLeftThumb`, `CenterRightThumb`, etc.) similar to what you have done for `CenterBottomThumb`. Calculate the new size and position based on the thumb being dragged and the current rotation.

```cs
private void CenterTopThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    // Logic to resize from the top, considering current rotation
    // Similar implementations are needed for other thumbs
}
```

For the resizing methods (`CenterTopThumb_DragDelta` and others), you need to implement similar logic that adjusts the size while considering the current rotation and position. That will prevent the rectangle from changing position unexpectedly while resizing.

Comment: Thank you, but I have no idea how to implement your recommendations in C#, I'm not strong in mathematics, could you write some code?

Comment: @codeDom Could you publish a project on GitHub which would allow me to build your current animation? That way, I can test out the code which is already present in this answer above (in csharp).

Comment: https://github.com/codedom-git/SelectionRect

Comment: @codeDom I will check that after work.

Comment: I really appreciate it

Comment: @codeDom So far, I have https://github.com/codedom-git/SelectionRect/compare/main...VonC:SelectionRect:fixRotation, but I still experience the same "defect" as you did.

Comment: Maybe @Andy can help us?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong transformation. `UIElement.LayoutTransform` is applied *before* the layout calculations. But you want to apply rotation on the final rendered object, *after* it is properly positioned in the layout. Therefore, you have to use `UIElement.RenderTransform`. Now, because the transformed object is already correctly positioned in the layout, transformations won't move the object out of place. This makes all your positioning code redundant.

To rotate around the center of an object (`UIElement`), simply set `UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin` to `new Point(0.5, 0.5)`. You can read the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin?view=windowsdesktop-8.0&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)%3Bk(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue#remarks) on the special `Point` definition that the `RenderTransformOrigin` property expects:

```xml
<Grid Name="RectGrid"
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
  <Grid.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}" />
  </Grid.RenderTransform>

<!-- Thumb controls etc. -->

</Grid>
```

```cs
private void RotateThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
  var currentLocation = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(this.RectGrid), Canvas.GetTop(this.RectGrid));
  var rotationCenter = new Point(currentLocation.X + this.RectGrid.Width / 2, currentLocation.Y + this.RectGrid.Height / 2);
  double newAngle = rotationCenter.GetAngle(mousePosition);

  var rotateTransform = this.RectGrid.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
  rotateTransform.Angle = newAngle;
}

private void RotateThumb_DragStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragStartedEventArgs e)
{
  // Not needed
}
```

To fix the translation you must use mouse coordinates instead of the drag delta reported by the Thumb. This is because once the Thumb was rotated beyond 90° the coordinates no longer match. The Thumb doesn't know it was rotated and that it top-left corner is now rotated by 90°.
To keep things simple, I recommend calculating the drag delta the classic way:

```cs
private Point DragStartLocation { get; set; }

private void CenterThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
  var mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this.Canvas1);
  var currentLocation = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(this.RectGrid), Canvas.GetTop(this.RectGrid));
  var dragDelta = new Point(mousePosition.X - this.DragStartLocation.X, mousePosition.Y - this.DragStartLocation.Y);

  var matrix = new Matrix();
  matrix.Translate(dragDelta.X, dragDelta.Y);
  Point transformedLocation = matrix.Transform(currentLocation);
  Canvas.SetLeft(this.RectGrid, transformedLocation.X);
  Canvas.SetTop(this.RectGrid, transformedLocation.Y);
  this.DragStartLocation = mousePosition;
}

private void CenterThumbBorder_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  this.DragStartLocation = e.GetPosition(this.Canvas1);
}
```

I also recommend to not handle the model in your view code. Instead, treat the model anonymously and handle the UI objects instead. The data is send to the model via data binding - if the layout related data is really needed by the data model/application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I checked your code, `CenterBottomThumb` works fine, but `RotateThumb` doesn't rotate around the center but around the top left corner, why is this happening? And another problem, after a 90 degree turn, if you drag the rectangle a few centimeters it jumps out of the window.

Comment: @codeDom Yep, exactly what I have at https://github.com/VonC/SelectionRect: rotate around the top-left corner, and jump at the next rotation after a drag.

Comment: You must set the RenderTransformOrigin. if not, the rotation will be around the top-left origin.

Comment: I have not revied the drag code, but it should be implemented using a TranslateTransform which is added to the same TransformGroup (together with the RotateTransform).

Comment: @VonC I will review your described scenario later.

Comment: @codeDom I have addressed your issues related to translating a rotated shape (>90°). The issue is related to the rotated Thumb reporting wrong delta coordinates once the top-left corner  gets rotated by >+-90°. I have also updated the rotation part so that it no longer depends on the DataContext.

Comment: I really appreciate your investment, I checked your code, currently the rectangle rotates perfectly around the midpoint, and does not jump after rotation when moving the rectangle, but when increasing the rectangle after rotation it changes position. could you fix it please?

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/WPFDevelopersOrg/WPFDevelopers#thumbdragandangleexamplexaml), a rectangle control that rotates without a problem, but when you change its size - after rotation - then there is the same problem that its position also changes.